# Anon. in Custom User Provider

Tags: php, security, symfony

I want to manage my users without Database, and check their JWT

I use [Guard](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html) and a Custom Service to Validate my JWT.

I Want to use even a custom [user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html), And If user doesn't have JWT I want to redirect to a new page or call an exception

this is my code

```
class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {

  /**
   * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
   */
  private $router;
  private $requestStack;

  /**
   * WebserviceUserProvider constructor.
   * @param RequestStack $router
   */
  public function __construct($router,RequestStack $requestStack) {
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
  }

  public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user) {
    if (!$user instanceof User) {
      throw new UnsupportedUserException(
              sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user))
      );
    }

    return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
  }

  public function loadUserByUsername($username) {

    if (!$token = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->headers->get('Authorization') ?: $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->query->get('token')) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException('Could not find user. Sorry!');
    }

    $user = new \AppBundle\Entity\User('MyUsername');
    $user->setJwtToken($token);
    return $user;
  }

  public function supportsClass($class) {
    return $class === 'AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser';
  }


}
```

And this is my service.yml

```
app.webservice_user_provider:
    class: AppBundle\Security\WebserviceUserProvider
    arguments: ['@router','@request_stack']
```

And My security.yml

```
user-providers
    providers:
        webservice:
            id: app.webservice_user_provider
```

When I visit a url with token in queryString

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/?token=my.token.jwt
```

My User is logged. 
When visit

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/
```

I have an user anon. ( My token is set to Anon. ) and I don't have an exception

If I change loadUserByUsername with

```
  public function loadUserByUsername($username) {

    if (!$token = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->headers->get('Authorization') ?: $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->query->get('token')) {
      $url = $this->router->generate('errorPage');
      return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    $user = new \AppBundle\Entity\User('MyUsername');
    $user->setJwtToken($token);
    return $user;
  }
```

I have this error

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getUsername" of class
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse". 500 Internal
>   Server Error - UndefinedMethodException

How can I redirect to a page if I dont'have a JWT ( or is not valid ), or have an exception ?